# curl logging into a website with username password and login button

Tags: curl

I use the below command to login to the site http://f7.masaladesi.com/htmlupload.php

```
curl -d "vb_login_username=username&vb_login_password=password" http://f7.masaladesi.com/htmlupload.php
```

But the reult is the same webpage of the initial one. I use the name attribute for login and password from the html form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the login endpoint you are looking for is `/login.php` :

```
curl -v -d "vb_login_username=username&vb_login_password=password&do=login" http://f7.masaladesi.com/login.php
```