# upload multiple attachment arrays to server webpage using curl

Tags: curl, post

The html page of the form data is as below

```
<form name="uploadform" id="uploadform" action="htmlupload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<table class="tborder" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" border="0" width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
    <td class="tcat">
        Upload Files
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="panelsurround" align="center">
    <div id="upload" class="panel">
        <div style="width:720px" align="left">
            <table border="0"><tr>
                <td>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                    <div><input name="attachment[]" type="file"></div>
                </td>
            </tr></table>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:6px">
            <input value="6ece14a18366a322c347c71cbfe87420" name="uploadcode" type="hidden" />
            <input value="upload" name="do" type="hidden" />
            <input value="upload" name="uploadbutton" onclick="onClickVerify();" class="button" type="button" accesskey="s" />
            <input type="reset" class="button" value="Reset Fields" accesskey="r" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="status" style="display:none;width:100%;">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

The public webpage is http://f7.masaladesi.com/htmlupload.php

I am trying to post files and upload using the curl command, tried the below two commands

```
curl -b cookie.txt -d "attachment[]=@1.png&do=upload" http://f7.masaladesi.com/htmlupload.php
curl -b cookie.txt -F "attachment[]=@1.png" http://f7.masaladesi.com/htmlupload.php
```

However it does not work. Below is the image of how the webpage looks like

[image: webpagelooks like]

Please give me a hint on how to achieve this, it is an array of selecting the attachments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @makeiteasy answer and your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423188/curl-logging-into-a-website-with-username-password-and-login-button), here is a working example :

```
# registration

curl -c cookie.txt \
     -d "vb_login_username=username&vb_login_password=password&do=login" \
     http://f7.masaladesi.com/login.php

# get an upload code value

uploadcode=$(curl -s -b cookie.txt http://f7.masaladesi.com/htmlupload.php | \
    awk 'match($0, /value=\"(.*)\" name="uploadcode"/,arr) { print arr[1] }')

# upload request 

curl -b cookie.txt -F "attachment[]=@cat.png" \
     -F "uploadcode=$uploadcode" -F "do=upload" \
     http://f7.masaladesi.com/htmlupload.php
```

This is :

- doing the registration to set the cookie
- request `http://f7.masaladesi.com/htmlupload.php` to extract `uploadcode`
- perform upload request with `multipart/form-data` content

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, you do not send the `uploadcode` field value. This may be your problem.

Also, note the difference between the `-d` and `-F` options. The latter one sends the content as `multipart/form-data`, which is what you need.

P.S. The link you provided doesn't work for me, so I'm just giving you suggestions here, which I'm unable to check myself.

Comment: I tried with curl -b cookie.txt --form "attachment[]=@1.png" --form "do=upload" http://f7.masaladesi.com/htmlupload.php. However the resulting webpage showed "invalid upload", which means the upload button works but something wrong while sending the attachment

Comment: Also the webpage is a forum, it is same as clicking on "Manage Attachments"  button after create a new thread. You will see an array of Browse button with an ' upload' at the end

Comment: That's because you're not sending the uploadcode value as I said in the answer. Use another --form "uploadcode=<value>". For the value see your HTML code.